# Project using array fields in MongoDB Java Driver

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have Collection as following. I have query this collection by **user**.

```
 {
      "user": "username",
      "sites": {
        "site": "abc",
        "keywords": [
          {
            "keyword": "keyword1",
            "dailyranks": [
              {
                "fild1": "value1"
              },
              {
                "fild2": "value2"
              },
              {
                "fild3": "value3"
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            "keyword": "keyword2",
            "dailyranks": [
              {
                "fild1": "value1"
              },
              {
                "fild2": "value2"
              },
              {
                "fild3": "value3"
              },  
            ]
          },
        ],
      }
    }
```

I want to get the result from the collection as follows, I want to get the last elements of keyword array in the collection

```
[
    {
        "keyword" : "keyword1"
        "fild2" : "value2",
        "fild3" : "value3"
    },
    {
       "keyword" : "keyword2"
        "fild2" : "value2",
        "fild3" : "value3"
    },
]
```

I have aggregate using **$project**, but didn't work out. help me to sort this out.

Code used-

```
BasicDBObject siteObject = new BasicDBObject();
siteObject.append("keywords", "$sites.keywords.keyword");
siteObject.append("lastrank", "$sites.keywords.dailyranks");

BasicDBList aDBList = new BasicDBList();
aaa.add(new BasicDBObject("user", modelLogin.getUSER_NAME()));

ArrayList<BasicDBObject> doc = new ArrayList<>();
doc.add(new BasicDBObject().append("$unwind", "$sites"));
doc.add(new BasicDBObject("$match", aDBList));
 doc.add(new BasicDBObject().append("$project", siteObject));
AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(doc);
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far, with your aggregation and $project?

Comment: @VinceBowdren question updated with source code
thanks

Comment: But there doesn't seem to be a $project clause in there?

Comment: sory my bad. I already again.

Comment: OK; and what output do you get from that?

Comment: keywords and dailyranks came with different arrays

Comment: What is your mongo server and driver version ?

Comment: it's 3.0. I don't want to get that out put on my way. let me know if u have your own way to get that done thanks

Comment: @Amal Madawa Are you looking to merge the `keyword` document with the documents in `dailyranks` ?

Comment: no. i dont want to merge

Comment: @AmalMadawa Sorry, I'm not able to understand your expected output. Can you explain little bit more ? Looks like you dont need `fild` ?

Comment: @Veeram it's like merging. can u merge it as your way ?

Comment: i want to get last 2 flid s with it's keyword
{
        "keyword" : "keyword1"
        "fild2" : "value2",
        "fild3" : "value3"
    },

Answer (score 2):

You can try below aggregation.

Use `$map` to transform the `Keywords` array.

Within `$map`,  use `$arrayElemAt` to project the last and second last values from `dailyranks` and `$let` operator to hold the result from `$arrayAtElem` and project the `fild` value.

```
db.coll.aggregate({
    $project: {
        keywords: {
            $map: {
                input: "$sites.keywords",
                as: "result",
                in: {
                    keyword: "$$result.keyword",
                    fild2: {$let: {vars: {obj: {$arrayElemAt: ["$$result.dailyranks", -2]}},in: "$$obj.fild2"}},
                    fild3: {$let: {vars: {obj: {$arrayElemAt: ["$$result.dailyranks", -1]}},in: "$$obj.fild3"}}
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Java Equivalent

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db  = mongoClient.getDatabase("db")
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("collection");
List<Document> results =
    collection.aggregate(
        Arrays.asList(
            Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("user", modelLogin.getUSER_NAME() )),
            Aggregates.project(
                Projections.fields(
                    new Document("keywords",
                        new Document("$map",
                        new Document("input", "$sites.keywords").
                        append("as", "result").
                        append("in",
                            new Document("keyword","$$result.keyword").
                                append("fild2",
                                    new Document("$let",
                                    new Document("vars", new Document("obj",
                                            new Document("$arrayElemAt", Arrays.asList("$$result.dailyranks", -2)))).
                                    append("in", "$$obj.fild2" ))).
                                append("fild3",
                                    new Document("$let",
                                    new Document("vars", new Document("obj",
                                            new Document("$arrayElemAt", Arrays.asList("$$result.dailyranks", -1)))).
                                    append("in", "$$obj.fild3" )))
                            )
                        )
                    )))
        )).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: @veerram  what is the purpose of  " fields" in  Aggregates.project(). got comping error

Comment: It's use to project the values. Updated. More here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html

Comment: got compile error like this,
no suitable method found for aggregate(List<Bson>)
    method DBCollection.aggregate(DBObject,DBObject...) is not applicable

Comment: What is your mongo java driver version ?

Comment: it is 3.3.0. I just update it to 3.4 but still getting the same error

Comment: got it. but "exception: invalid operator '$arrayElemAt'' on server..." error occurred. what should i do ?

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: it's 3.0. do i need to upgrade ?

Comment: Please if you can. `$arrayElemAt` was added in Mongo 3.2. You should upgrade to 3.4